# json_encode no codifica array con más de un dato interno

Tags: php, mysql, json

Tengo una serie de campos que quiero mandar dentro de un array json a un archivo js. Después de buscar el error por varios minutos, me di cuenta que si al json_encode() le coloco un array con solo un dato, este funciona y se codifica en formato json perfectamente. En cambio, cuando tiene de más de uno, el js recibe un "null". No tengo idea del porqué de esto. ¿Alguien podría darme una mano?

Código:

```
$nom = $row["nom"];

$ape = $row["ape"];

$tel = $row["tel"];

$domicilio = $row["domicilio"];

$email = $row["email"];

echo json_encode(array("ok" => true, "nom" => $nom, "ape" => $ape, "tel" => $tel, "domicilio" => $domicilio, "email" => $email));
```

Nota: Las variables que toman su valor de los campos de la base de datos funcionan bien. Y con "funcionan bien" me refiero a que cada una toma los valores esperados. El problema está lisa y llanamente en el json_encode o en el array.

Comment: Uso Ajax para hacer la petición, y dentro del "success" tengo un código a ejecutar con la respuesta del php. Sin embargo, al haber un error, comenté el código y solo dejé algo así: success: function(respuesta){ console.log($.parseJSON(respuesta)); }

Comment: Según la documentación http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php también está bien, entonces todo debería funcionar.... por eso me gustaría ver el resultado de `echo json_encode(..)`

Comment: Encontré que el error está en "domicilio". Si le dejo todos los otros campos, el ajax me lo decodifica bien al json. La verdad, no lo entiendo. O sea, el error está en domicilio. Sin embargo, cuando hice un "echo" normal con "$row["domicilio"]" funciona bien.

Comment: Encontré el error. El valor que tengo en la base de datos en el campo "domicilio" tenía un caracter especial, por lo que al agregarle un "utf8_encode()" a domicilio, el código funcionó perfectamente. De todas formas, gracias por tu intención de ayuda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encontré el error. El valor que tengo en la base de datos en el campo "domicilio" tenía un caracter especial, por lo que al agregarle un "utf8_encode()" al "row" domicilio, el código funcionó perfectamente.

Comment: bienvenido a la familia de SOes, sigue adelante! Tienes madera para ser buen desarrollador :D Éxitos en todo!

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por el buen deseo!! E igualmente para ti!

Comment: muchísimas de nada @Criss